# Here Maps - iOS - MSDKUI Changing ui elements based on local language

Tags: ios, here-api

I am using MSDKUI to display UI elements with navigation. I can't find the way to change the default language to the phones local language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HERE Mobile SDK UI Kit for iOS should have already support for 14+ languages. Please check the documentation to verify what languages are available.

Within Xcode you have to add the desired languages you want to support. If the language is not yet supported, then the device will fallback to English.

For example, Xcode 9 and Xcode 10 already support base internationalization. Verify that the checkbox is marked:

- Select your project in Xcode's file navigator. Make sure the project and not the target is selected. You should see the checkbox labelled **'Use Base Internationalization'**. If it is not selected, please select it.
- With the **+/-** buttons above you can add or remove supported languages for your app. Make sure the selected language will match the ones from the HERE Mobile SDK UI Kit.
- Set a language on the device via phone settings. Restart your app: The components should be localized now.

Note that this procedure does not contain any HERE specific steps. It's just the standard way on iOS how to add localization to your app. Once the app is properly localized the HERE Mobile SDK UI Kit will recognize the language and display the current language, if available.

Comment: What if the language is not supported/added to the MSDKUI yet? Is it possible to add the translations to the MSDKUI library, recompile and then add the library to the main project?

Comment: Exactly, this would be the expected way. The localizations can be found here: https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-ios/tree/master/MSDKUI/Assets - so it should be possible to extend them.